# ListView within ListView in android application

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am doing a project that currently requires a list and when a particular item from the list is clicked another list activity appears. Is there any solution as to how to move from one listview activity to another. I am currently using http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ as a reference for my ListView.

Comment: I'm afraid some clarification is needed. Your title implies a two-level list view.  If that's what you need, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html . Otherwise, if you need to open another activity upon item click, just do so using Intent and context.startActivity().

Comment: Use 2 List Fragments, and switch between them from same Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be:

Create the second ListView activity and implement the first ListActivity with a OnItemClickListener that opens the second ListViewActivity by using an regular Intent.

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                    long arg3) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(FirstListActivity.this, SecondListActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("pos", position);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE:**

I have wrote an simple example list application. You may use it for insperation. The code that could open the Second list activity is included, but commented out. If you get this example to run, you are getting closer. Then you can try comment out the Intent code.

```
package com.adpog.listviewexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the ListView resource.   
        ListView mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.my_list );  

        // Set the Adapter as the ListView's adapter.  
        mainListView.setAdapter( new BaseAdapter(){

            // Create and populate a List of planet names.  
            String[] planets = new String[] {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune" };    

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return planets.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int pos) {
                return planets[pos-1];
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int pos) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
                if(view == null){
                    /**
                     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" 
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                            <ImageView 
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                             />
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/item_text" 
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:text="Text not set" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    */
                    view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, null);
                }
                return view;
            }
        });        

        mainListView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView< ? > arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Log.d("ListView", "Pos: " + arg2 + ", long : "+arg3);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test " + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /* Alternative way; opens a new Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondListViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", pos);
                startActivity(intent);
                */
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView< ? > arg0) {
            }
        });

        /**
         * Implement an action for each item click.
         */
        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView< ? > arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Log.d("ListView", "OnClickPos: " + arg2 + ", long : "+arg3);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test " + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have something like a list with 4 options and each option has another 3 options inside and each of the 3 options would probably have something like a picture and description in it. is it going to be possible to handle?

Comment: It is possible. Implement the second ListView activity with an Adapter that is capable to display an icon and a text for each list item. Initialize the listview with a data-array identified via an intent extra.

Comment: I have tried several times but i'm not sure of how to implement it, i'm not sure if its because of my understanding since i'm quite new. Could you show an example to put me on the right track? Many Thanks!!

Comment: Wow!! Thanks! But what if i were to list the information from an xml file, for example [link](http://pastebin.com/ikFvhsQ3)??

Comment: Thank i would put the xml file in the asset folder and read it from there.

Answer (score 0):

api provides [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) . your requirement looks very close to it